# What is the correct way to start `:pg`'s default scope in an Elixir 1.12 application?

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

The `:pg2` module was removed in OTP 24. It's replacement is `:pg`. According to the [documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/man/pg.html):

> Default scope pg is started automatically when kernel(6) is configured to do so.

From a mix-based Elixir 1.12 application, what is the right way to configure the kernel to start the default `:pg` scope automatically? So far, I've been doing this but it seems really hack-y makes writing library code that doesn't have a `start/2` function impossible:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do

    # Ew, gross:
    {:ok, _pid} = :pg.start_link()

    children() |> Supervisor.start_link([strategy: :one_for_one, name: __MODULE__])
  end

  def children, do: []
end
```

Comment: `** (Mix) Could not start application pg: could not find application file: pg.app`

:pg isn't an app, it's part of the Erlang kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own [`child_spec`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#t:child_spec/0) for that module:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Supervisor.start_link(children(), strategy: :one_for_one, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  defp children, do: [pg_spec()]

  defp pg_spec do
    %{
      id: :pg,
      start: {:pg, :start_link, []}
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Good idea. That will get the supervision tree up cleanly, but it still doesn't "configure the kernel" (whatever that means from Elixir) as the OTP documentation says should be done.

Comment: @Clay you cannot easily configure `kernel` in Elixir. The easiest way to do so right now is probably to run `env ERL_FLAGS="-kernel start_pg true" mix` in development and do full restart in the production.